# Angular router-outlet - Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment

Tags: angular, angular-router, router-outlet

I apologize in advance because I have seen several posts about this, but despite many attempts I can't solve my problem.

I am on Angular 13.3.9

I try to use the outlet router as described here: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet

My goal is to load components according to the routes at different places in the html code.

Here is the simplest code tried:

**Router**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'challenge/pwd', component: ChallengePwd, outlet: 'challenge-pwd' },
  { path: 'identifier', component: Identifier, outlet: 'identifier' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<main>
    <section>
        <logo-loader></logo-loader>
        <section class="presentation">
            <router-outlet name="identifier"></router-outlet>
            <router-outlet name="challenge-pwd"></router-outlet>
        </section>
    </section>
</main>
```

When I try to access the url
http://localhost:4201/identifier

I get an error : `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'identifier'`

I also tried encapsulating the outlet routes in a parent component like this:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'oauth',
    component: MainPage,
    children: [
      { path: 'challenge/pwd', component: ChallengePwd, outlet: 'challenge-pwd' },
      { path: 'identifier', component: Identifier, outlet: 'identifier' }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.component.html

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

main.page.html

```html
<main>
    <section>
        <logo-loader></logo-loader>
        <section class="presentation">
            <router-outlet name="identifier"></router-outlet>
            <router-outlet name="challenge-pwd"></router-outlet>
        </section>
    </section>
</main>
```

But nothing works, I keep getting this error `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'identifier'`

Comment: Could u pls accept my answer if it works for you ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think It's a good way for achieving your goal. There is a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-zzptuu?file=app/app.component.ts) for you

First, you need a primary router, which doesn't have a name, so your routes should like this

```js
      { path: 'oauth', component: OauthComponent },
      { path: 'challenge-pwd', component: ChallengeComponent, outlet: 'challenge-pwd' },
      { path: 'identifier', component: IdentifierComponent, outlet: 'identifier' },
```

Unfortunately, the URL isn't friendly, you should respect the syntax

```
/primaryRoute(routerOutletName:path)
```

So un example of your URL should be

```
http://localhost:4200/oauth(challenge-pwd:challenge-pwd)
```

Answer (score 0):

your correct url is: http://localhost:4201/oauth/identifier

you setup path to `oauth`
and children of these is `identifier`

Comment: for the second, yes it's my correct path, that's not resolve the problem

Comment: what happen if you call this url: http://localhost:4201/oauth/identifier ?

Comment: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'identifier'